# Display text from tap counter on two views

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.5

So I have my app and I have a view with a tap counter and the displaying label. I would like it to display the text on the main view (it does now) but also on a second view.

So how could i display the text on the other view. If more details needed, please email.

STEPS TO REPRODUCE FOR TAP COUNTER
The .h file:

```
@interface Level1 : UIViewController {

int counter;

IBOutlet UILabel *count;

}

-(IBAction)plus;

@property (assign) int counter;

@end
```

The .m file:

```
@synthesize counter;

- (void) viewDidLoad {

counter=1;

count.text = @"0";

[super viewDidLoad];
}

-(IBAction)plus {

counter=counter + 1;

count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",counter];
}

@end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can create model with your counter value which will be shared among both views.

Model is usually created with singleton pattern. In this case it could be done this way:

your .h file:

```
@interface CounterModel
@property (assign) NSInteger counter;// atomic
+ (id)sharedInstance;
- (void)increment;
@end
```

your .m file:

```
@implementation CounterModel
@synthesize counter;

- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
    }
    return self;
}

+ (id)sharedInstance
{
    static CounterModel *instance = nil;
    if (instance == nil)
    {
        instance = [[CounterModel alloc] init];
    }
    return instance;
}

- (void)increment
{
    counter++;
}

@end
```

Then from one view controller you can call:

```
[[CounterModel sharedInstance] increment];
```

and from second you can read this updated value by calling:

```
[[CounterModel sharedInstance] counter];
```

To achieve what you want you could set UILabel value read from model's counter value in viewWillAppear method.

Comment: I dont quite under stand, could you maybe Skype me and explain .

Comment: Please specify what exactly you don't understand so I can comment on that. Basically the model I refer to will be your new class. Please read on Model View Controller [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW1) to understand this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use delegate to pass data to en another view. When you load the second view probably via the first view, you can set your first view as the datasource.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e5l0QOyxZvI

You can also use the notification center to send message to another view.